# Loop not working in php

Tags: php, loops, count, echo

I am trying to do a loop in php. What is printed is 4 for the count of "multi" and 0 for $x. That's right, it only goes through the loop once despite the count being 4. What is going wrong?

```
echo count($xmlData->multi);
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($xmlData->multi) - 1; $x++) {
echo $x;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your code is exactly  like you pasted it here but you're missing the closing bracket `}`. Besides that it looks good to me.

Comment: <= count($xmlData->multi) - 1 is basically < count($xmlData->multi) minus a couple of cpu cycles

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing I notice when I look at this code, is that you are missing a closing bracket ( } ), other than that I don't see anything else, you have all your semicolons, you have all your variable declaration symbols ( $ ). Try adding the ending bracket and that might get your loop working.